# Remove default fields from Wordpress post edit page

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello dear stackoverflow users!

Is there any method of removing the **default** fields in WP?

I want to **at least hide them** from editor because my client will have a lot of custom fields to fill there, I want to reduce visual noise on the screen.

I include a screenshot of what I want to get rid of.

**Post editor screenshot**

[image]

I have tried this:

```
function remove_my_post_metaboxes() {
   remove_meta_box( 'postimagediv','post','side' ); // Featured Image
}
add_action('admin_menu','remove_my_post_metaboxes');
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out, found that:

- Topic about this is on WordPress GitHub, but it has not been resolved.
- Code to remove those works only if classic editor is enabled.
- There is a plugin to activate classic editor.
- So basically it's possible